# Deprecating a renamed attribute in Ruby YARD documentation

Tags: ruby, deprecated, yard

I have been renaming some attributes in my Ruby [mqtt gem](https://github.com/njh/ruby-mqtt), to match the new [MQTT specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/mqtt-v3.1.1.html). I have been doing this by renaming the attribute and then using alias_method to make sure the old methods still work.

Here is an example of what I have done for renaming the attributes:

```
# The level number of the protocol
attr_accessor :protocol_level

# @deprecated Please use {#protocol_level} instead
alias_method :protocol_version, :protocol_level

# @deprecated Please use {#protocol_level=} instead
alias_method :protocol_version=, :protocol_level=
```

However in the generated YARD docs, it doesn't mark it as deprecated and actually makes it look like it is a good alternative name!

```
- (Object) protocol_level
Also known as: protocol_version
The level number of the protocol
```

What is the best way to do this? Should I define the old attribute names using a normal method definition instead? I am keen to keep the code concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#deprecated), you are supposed to mark a method as deprecated. Something like

```
# @deprecated Use {#bar} instead.
def foo
  bar
end

def bar
  ...
end
```

I realize this is not as succinct as using `alias_method`, but I think this is the only way to do it with YARD.

Comment: Agree that there doesn't seem to be a better way of doing this.